# getter setter and objects not existing in the current context

Tags: c#, oop, getter-setter

Hi am new to OOP and I am doing a task right now however I cant link the customer class and objects into my main program. It says that it doesn't exist in the current context. This maybe also due to me not understanding the name spaces completely and may have the names of the class in the file directory being incorrect but if I am honest I don't know.

Main program (file direct name is MainProg)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //New Customer Account Sequence 

        //Customer customerOne = new Customer();

        Console.WriteLine("Customer Details:\n-----------------\n");
        Console.Write("Please enter cutomer forename: ");

        customerOne.Forename = Console.ReadLine();
        customerOne.Surname = Console.ReadLine();
        customerOne.Address = Console.ReadLine();
        customerOne.Town = Console.ReadLine();
        customerOne.Postcode = Console.ReadLine();     

        CurrentAccount accountCurrOne = new CurrentAccount();

        //accountCurrOne.AccountNumber = 1000; 

        SavingsAccount accountSavOne = new SavingsAccount();
        accountSavOne.AccountNumber = 1001;
        accountCurrOne.Open(customerOne);
        accountSavOne.Open(customerOne);

        //Initial deposit 
        decimal depositAmount;
        depositAmount = decimal.Parse(Utility.Console.Ask("Enter initial deposit: "));

        accountCurrOne.Deposit(depositAmount);
        accountSavOne.Deposit(depositAmount);

        // End of New Customer Account Sequence 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Customer Class (Name in file directory is CustomerOne)

```
class CustomerOne : BankAccount
{
    protected string _Forename;
    protected string _Surname;
    protected string _Address;
    protected string _Town;
    protected string _Postcode;

    public string Forename
    {
        get { return _Forename; }
        set { Forename = value; }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return _Surname; }
        set { Surname = value; }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return _Address; }
        set { Address = value; }
    }

    public string Town
    {
        get { return _Town; }
        set { Town = value; }
    }

    public string Postcode
    {
        get { return _Postcode; }
        set { Postcode = value; }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me where I am messing up?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking here. Please provide a [mre], the code you show here is effectively meaningless.

Comment: Uncomment the line `//Customer customerOne = new Customer();` and your code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call properties and methods of an object, you must instantiate it.
The problem is the following line that you commented:

```
//Customer customerOne = new Customer();
```

This line creates a new instance of the Customer class. Once you create an instance with the keyword `new` and assigned it to a `variable`, you can call class methods and properties with `variable.Property` or `variable.Method()`.
This applies for classes that are not Static.

A reference for instances: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/objects